# How to disable PLINQ partitioning/batching

Tags: .net, plinq

PLINQ internally batches the items that it takes in order to reduce overhead. Since my items are very memory intensive I'd like to minimize any buffering that exists in the PLINQ query pipeline. How can I disable partitioning/batching entirely?

The code looks like this:

```
var myItems = Enumerable.Range(0, 10000000).Select(_ => new byte[1 << 30]);
var results =
 myItems
 .AsParallel()
 .WithMaxDegreeOfParallelism(4)
 .Select(F)
 .ToList();
```

In this code I'd expect the maximum number of (big) items that are ineligible for garbage collection to be 4.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what are you doing, ideally including some code? There are different kinds of batching in PLINQ and they have different ways to disable them.

Comment: @svick right, I should have provided code right away. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to [create a `Paritioner`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh136328(v=vs.110).aspx) over your source, which specifies `NoBuffering`, and then use that in your PLINQ query:

```
var myItems = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Select(_ => new byte[1 << 30]);
var myPartitioner = Partitioner.Create(myItems, EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering);
var results =
    myPartitioner
    .AsParallel()
    .WithDegreeOfParallelism(4)
    .Select(F)
    .ToList();
```

This query works for me, but throws `OutOfMemoryException` if I skip the partitioner (just like your original query).